# Linq IQueryable short circuiting an empty search parameter

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, expression-trees, short-circuiting

I have a generic repository with the following method

```
IQueryable<T> GetAllByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
```

I'm now trying to provide a search feature through the front end, where one or more parameters might have been entered or left blank. I'm having problems short-circuiting the expression for empty parameters.

The problem can be demonstrated by calling the following example on the repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Search(string param)
{
    var filteredFoos = _fooRepository.GetAllByFilter(
          f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) || f.Something == param );

    return filteredFoos.ToList(); // throws exception
}
```

Enumerating the query with `ToList()` throws a `System.NullReferenceException` if `param` is `null`.

I neither understand this nor know how to fix it, so any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** in response to the comments below, I added a null check. My actual code looks like this now

```
var test1 = _repository.GetAllByFilter(
     r => r != null && 
         (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) 
              || (r.Field != null && r.Field.IndexOf(param.Trim()) != -1)));

var test2 = test1.ToList(); // exception here
```

I'm still not seeing where the problem could be.

**EDIT:** in response to comment, the generic repository `GetAllByFilter` code:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return _dataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(expression);
}
```

note that if I run a simple `GetAll` query

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
 {
     return _dataContext.GetTable<T>();
 }
```

on the same table, no `null` records are returned (as expected).

Comment: that doesnt sound right, are you sure that there arent occasions when the 'f' parameter is null, and 'f.Something' throws the exception ?

Comment: I don't believe so, the query runs fine as long as a non-null string is passed in as the param. I don't see how f could be null?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - The only way `f` would be null is if `_fooRepository` returned a null item. Are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: Further to your update; I haven't the foggiest idea.

Comment: Can we see the code for GetAllByFilter()?

Comment: This could be down to my lack of understanding of Linq, but do you need to pass in an expression? Can't you just pass in the Func?

Comment: @Matt: you need an expression in order to build the IQueryable. I only recently discovered this myself, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873753/linq-repository-and-gettablet

Comment: @fear: I learn something new every day at SO!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace - would be interesting to know exactly who/what is throwing the null ref.

Comment: maybe linq2sql has some internal problems with that query.. :D param should not throw that exception, and I dont think it returns null-items? If so, f.Something could be a problem...

Comment: GetAll() returns Enumerable.Empty?

Comment: The exception's thrown on string.IsNullOrEmpty(). I thought it was pretty obvious so I didn't point it out. That's why my answer took that out of the Linq query and switched between to Linq expressions.

Comment: Forgot to elaborate. string.IsNullOrEmpty() can NOT be translated from linq expression into sql query. This is a limitation of EF query translator that does not recognise string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 2):

keep it simple:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Search(string param)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
    {
        return this.fooRepository.GetAll().ToArray();
    }

    return this.fooRepository.GetAllByFilter(o => o.Field.Contains(param.Trim())).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: There was no "GetAll()" method when the question was created. Bit naive to assume it's a one man project where you are allowed to modify all parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

cake.

```
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Search(string param)
    {
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> shortCircuit = a => true;
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> normal = a => a.Something == param;

        var filteredFoos = _fooRepository.GetAllByFilter(
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) ? shortCircuit : normal);

        return filteredFoos.ToList(); // no more exception.
    }
```

You just gotta remember, you can't throw anything into those IQueryable methods and expect them to understand. You can probably make shortCircuit expression to static.